# Why does my loop always go through even though the conditions aren't always met?

Tags: java, android, rest, loops, timer

I am making a chat app, checking if there are any new messages using a REST call. On a one second timer I am checking if the id of the last message in list is the same as the last id of newly downloaded list. If it isn't the same id (there are new messages) then update the recycerview. The problem is that it keeps on updating without any new messages and I am not sure why. Most likely it's a simple problem though i can't seem to find it.

Timer:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                readMessages(myId, chatId);
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

REST call:

```
private void readMessages(String myId, String chatId) {

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(userApi.class);
        Call<LinkedList<Messages>> call = apiInterface.getMessages(myId, chatId);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LinkedList<Messages>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LinkedList<Messages>> call, Response<LinkedList<Messages>> response) {
                mList.clear();
                mList = response.body();
                if (mList2.isEmpty() || mList2.getLast().getId().equals(mList.getLast().getId())) {
                    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(ChatActivity.this, mList, Integer.parseInt(myId));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                    mList2.clear();

                    mList2 = (LinkedList) mList.clone();
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, mList2.getLast().getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LinkedList<Messages>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any loop here.

Comment: basically the timer works like a loop and it shouldn't always go trough the if statement

Comment: I can't see the declaration of mList2

Comment: Both mList and mList2 are declared like simple Linked lists above the methods. Didn't think it was necessary to add it so I just skiped it. Anyway here are the declarations: LinkedList<Messages> mList = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<Messages> mList2 = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: Should the second half of the if-statement read `!mList2.getLast().getId().equals(mList.getLast().getId())`? The way it is currently written means that mList2 is updated of both lists have the same `getLast().getId()`, whereas your description implies that you only want to update if the ids are not the same.

Comment: As funny as it is i just noticed it myself with the help of @AlexisDufrenoy comment. Rly sad but it was that simple. Ty for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your `if` statement is `mList2.isEmpty()` (I assume `mList` and `mList2` are actually the same thing). A wild guess for a reason why each call to `onResponse` passes `if` the test would be that the list is actually empty. Try step-by-step debug and placing a breakpoint on the `if` line to check, and if so, take a look at your REST service in order to understand why it is responding with an empty list.

Comment: It is empty on the first timer tick, though i intended it to be that way. Every other time it goes through the loop mList2 has data in it.

Comment: Did you check that to be sure?

Comment: I did with the toast message. It always shows the last id.

Comment: So mList2 is the old (from the previous loop) mList. And the condition to pass the if test is either if the old mList is empty or if the current mList's and the old mList's last element have the same id. So you need to check which of those conditions is true. There is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

So in your code what exactly is supposed to happen if the condition is not met?

If see that there is an `if` statement. And let us assume we are not going into it because conditions are not met. So where is the else statement? What is the code supposed to do if the conditions don't match? As there is nothing else to be done in function, the control will return back from the function to the timer.

You can probably try putting timer inside the if statement, so it will only run when your conditions are met.

Do you think this was the problem?

Comment: I acctaully wanted it to be an endless loop that has a function only if there is a new message. Trying to emulate a firebase type of a chat app.

Comment: You can try calling the function back inside the else statement. That way it can only leave if the ```if``` statement is met or there is a failure.